drawing a radius circle on react-map-gl map
I am currently working with react-map-gl and need to set a marker with an range circle around it.
I can set the marker by importing Marker from react-map-gl.
But i am stuck on the radius which should be based on km around the marker.
Does anyone have a solution for this?

I figured out a solution to draw a radius.
import circle from '@turf/circle';
import MapGL, { ScaleControl, useMap, Marker, Source, Layer } from "react-map-gl";

export function Map({ range, coordinates }) {
  const center = [coordinates.lng, coordinates.lat];
  const radius = range ?? 30; // set fallback to 30 Kilometer

  const circleData = useMemo(() => {
    const options = { steps: 64, units: 'kilometers' };
    const myCircle = circle(center, radius, options);
    return myCircle;
  }, [center, radius]);

  return (
    <MapGL>
      <Source id="circle-source" type="geojson" data={circleData}>
        <Layer
         id="circle-layer"
         type="fill"
         paint={{
          'fill-color': '#888',
          'fill-opacity': 0.4,
         }}
        />
      </Source>
    </MapGL> 
  )
}

